# jQuery: create a div and inserting elements inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a simple program where the user can fill can input text and select an image (url or local) and show the selected info in a div bellow. I was making it with an existent div, but in case we don't know how many times the user will insert information, it is not possible to do it this way.

Therefore, how could this be done creating a div and inserting the content inside it?

```
User:
<div>
  <input type="text" id="user">Add image
  <form id="image">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="url">URL
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="local">PC
  </form>
  <input type="text" id="url" style="display:none">
  <input type="file" id="local" style="display:none">
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  <div id="enter"></div>
  <p id="p1"></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#image input').on('change', function () {
        if ($('input[name=radio]:checked', '#image').val() == "url") {
            $("#url").css('display', 'block');
            $("#local").css('display', 'none');
        } else if ($('input[name=radio]:checked', '#image').val() == "local") {
            $("#url").css('display', 'none');
            $("#local").css('display', 'block');
        }
    });

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $("#p1").text($("#user").val());
if($("#url").css('display', 'none')==true){
$("#enter").append("img").prop("src", file.val());
}else{
$("#enter").append("img").prop("src", url.val());
}
    });
});
```

Comment: Code is much easier to read if you properly indent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
$("#enter").append("<img src='" + $("#url").val() + "'>");
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hY0sVn?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides you a lot of ways to create elements.
You can create it with the `$.fn` selector:

```
$("<div>", {
    class: "Your custom classes",
    id: "random",
    style: "border: none",
    anyAttribute: "itsValue"
}).addClass("itsChainable")
.html("<a href=\"nowhere.com\">Im a link!!</a>")
.appendTo("body")
```

Comment: I wish i had 15 points to vote you up, your comment made it quite clear to me, thanks a lot!!

Comment: It doesn't matter, I hope it helps you. :)

Comment: In order to not open another question with partially the same topic, why does it not charge the local image with "$("#change").append("<img src='" + $("#local").val() + "'>");"  ? change is a blank div and it does charge the image icon but not the image itself, do you know why?